# How to get the total sum of several function calls in a double loop

Tags: matlab, function, for-loop, recursion

I'm trying to implement a recursive function in Matlab. Actually I want to implement this function into HDL Coder in MATLAB. But hte problem is that Matlab does not support the recursive function as I've written it.

It was supposed to run 100 times with random input [0,255] data.

In this case, What am I supposed to do to resolve this recursive implementation problem?

- test.m

  ```
  for y = 1:480
      for x = 1:640
          R_in = rand(255,1);
          srcX = 640;
          srcY = 480;
          function [R_out] = test_function(R_in, srcX, srcY)
      end
  end
  ```
- test_function.m

  ```
  function [R_out] = test_function(R_in, srcX, srcY)

      R_out = R_out+ (R_in * (1/(srcX*srcY)));

  end
  ```

Comment: Can you add the math/analytical function definition to your question? Since your code doesn't work, it's not very clear what this function tries to do and we can't really help you out fixing it. The gist though, is correctly stated in Tim Mironov's answer.

Comment: @tryman Yes, of course.  my code can have a fault, because I'm keep trying to find the answer. I've add the test code for test_function for more understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issues:

- Don't use the `function` keyword when calling a function, only when declaring one.
- You can't use `R_out` in your `test_function` until it has been declared. i.e. `R_out = R_out + ...` doesn't work because `R_out` doesn't exist yet to be used in the right hand side of this equation.

It looks like your code should be as follows:

```
%% test_function.m
function [R_out] = test_function(R_in, srcX, srcY)
    R_out = R_in * (1/(srcX*srcY));
end

% ------------------------------------------ %

%% test.m
% Note that the R_out here is completely independent of the R_out above.
% They are declared in different scopes, and not visible to each other.
% It would be clearer to call them different names

srcX = 640; % We can declare srcX and srcY before the loops as they don't change
srcY = 480;
R_out = 0;  % Initialise R_out to 0
for y = 1:480
    for x = 1:640
        R_in = rand(255,1);
        R_out = R_out + test_function(R_in, srcX, srcY); % Increment R_out
    end
end
```

However, there is nothing "recursive" here, you are simply calling a function.

This would only become recursive if `test_function` called itself.

Answer (score 0):

The way you wrote the function - you use `R_out` before it was declared. In order to write a proper recursion function the `test_function` has to call for itself while some condition is met, in your case 100 consequtive calls.